# c# iTextSharp: replace pdf fields from Database (DB row to List<string>)

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

This is my function which replaces the `fields` (`List<string>`) of a `pdf form` with some values (`List<string>`):

```
public static void VerySimpleReplaceText(string OrigFile, string ResultFile, List<string> pdfFields, List<string> replaceStrings)
        {
            //get size of list
            int listSize = pdfFields.Count();

            //create PdfReader object to read the source file
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(OrigFile);
            //PdfStamper object to modify the content of the PDF
            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(ResultFile, FileMode.Create));
            //get form fields
            AcroFields form = stamp.AcroFields;
            //fill in text fiels
            for (int i = 0; i< listSize; i++)
                form.SetField(pdfFields[i], replaceStrings[i]);

            stamp.Close();
            //view the result pdf file

        }
```

Each row of the table `dbo.PDFFormFields` contains the `fields' values` of a `pdf form`. How I can write my query in order to get all the columns of a row and convert them to `List<string>`? This is my query until now...

```
var valuesList = (from pf in dc.PDFFormFields
                          where pf.id == 10
                          select pf);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with iText?